# How are type aliases resolved when the System directive is missing?

Tags: c#, types, compiler-errors, directive

`bool`,`int`,and`string` (to name a few), are all aliases of `System` types.
They can all be used without the `System` directive being included.
Yet the types they alias can't be used without the `System` directive.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool b;     //valid
        Boolean b2; //compiler error

        int i;      //valid
        Int32 i2;   //compiler error

        string s;   //valid
        String s2;  //compiler error
    }
}
```

I have few questions as to why this works.

- Is the compiler making an exception for these commonly used types?
- Is the `System` directive being looked at to determine the aliasing,
  but not being looked at for the other types?
- Is it always safe to
  use `bool`, `int`,`string`, etc without the `System` directive?

Comment: I am going to assume the compiler swapped the aliases out with the fully qualified name i.e. `bool b` is `System.Boolean b` at compile.

Comment: They are not just aliases, they are *keywords* in the C# language.  Works anywhere, anytime, even a 100 years from now when everybody giggles about our stone-age computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the compiler making an exception for these commonly used types?

Yes.

> Is the System directive being looked at to determine the aliasing, but not being looked at for the other types?

Yes.  Well, sort of.  There is no System directive.  There is a `using` directive, with which you can import the `System` namespace, which defines the types.

> Is it always safe to use bool, int,string, etc without the System directive?

Yes.

Many modern languages like C# are heavily inspired from C++, which is in turn heavily inspired from C.  The C language had taken the innovative stance of complete separation between compiler and runtime.  The compiler of C was (is) making absolutely no assumptions about the standard libraries.  In theory, it is possible to write C programs that do not include the standard libraries.

However, languages like C# accept that there is significant merit in having a certain degree of collusion between the compiler and the runtime.  Many C# keywords depend on support from the runtime.  A very good example of that, the `yield return` keyword.  Other examples are the types that your question is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx you see that the built-in boolean type is an alias for `System.Boolean` and not `Boolean` that is the aliases are *fully qualified*.

So when you write `int x;` it gets aliased to `System.Int32 x;` and not just *`Int32`* or else they might collide if you defined a type called `Int32` in your own namespace.

Using these built in types should always be safe, you do not have same problem as C/C++ sometimes has where "built in" types have different underlying types and therefore return different values when `sizeof` is called on them depending on platform.